# Access Belkin router which has been configured as an Access Point from browser

Tags: wireless-networking, router, home-networking, wireless-access-point

When my Belkin router was used a router, it could be easily accessed from any browser by its IP address.  But recently, to use its wireless capability in conjunction with a Clear modem Series G, I had to configure it as an Access Point instead of a router.  (I think because the Series G also functions as router and there can't be 2 routers on the same network).

Everything is working now.  Except I don't know how to access the Belkin router management console from the browsers anymore.  I would need to know this because later if I need to change the wireless encryption code, I wouldn't be able to.

Have you ran into the same issue?  Please share.

Comment: There can be two routers on the same network, but in your case you probably only want one of them acting as the DHCP server.  What are the IP addresses of your routers and access points?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to factory reset the AP, connect it to your pc (directly with crossover cable), login to the default ip(192.168.1.1 or whatever it is), and set a static IP for the device. Alternately you can use [Angry Ip Scanner](http://www.angryip.org/w/Home) to scan the whole subnet it will return all the attached devices IP's and MAC addresses. Check the label on the Belkin and match the MAC address there to the MAC's that come up in angry IP scanner output. This will tell you the Belkin's IP address that you can then use to log into the web UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can reliably find a quiet access point with a free port scanner like [nmap](http://nmap.org). A command like:

```
nmap -p80 --open 192.168.0.1-254
```

will show all web servers on your local network. Using nmap's GUI, Zenmap, the search looks like this:

[image: Zenmap showing open port search]

You should replace `192.168.0` with the first three parts of your computer’s local IP (find it on [Mac](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14009) or [Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/find-computers-ip-address#1TC=windows-7)). `-p80` restricts the scan to port 80, which web servers use, and `--open` restricts the results to open ports. Then you can just try each result that comes up until you find the right one. In my case, I know 192.168.0.1 is my router, so 192.168.0.6 has to be my access point.